# Set a PHP Cookie to expire at midnight

Tags: php, cookies

I know how to set a PHP Cookie and how to make it expire in a set time, say 24 hours but how can I make a cookie expire at minute before the servers midnight everyday, so 23:59?

I've tried the following but it doesn't seem to set for me?

```
setcookie("cons", 1, mktime(24, 0, 0) - time(), "/");
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You might find [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) useful in these situations.

```
<?php
setcookie('cons', 1, strtotime('today 23:59'), '/');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$dt=explode(':',date('j:n:Y',time()));
$midnight1=mktime(0,0,0,$dt[1],$dt[0],$dt[2]);
$midnight2=$midnight1+(1*24*60*60);
$rest = $midnight2 - time();
setcookie("cons1", 1 ,time()+$r);
```

I tested this code cookie will automatically delete at 00:00 every day.